# KeyError: "TURKEY" when ingesting the Quandl bundle

Tags: python, finance, quandl, zipline

I have created a Anaconda Environment to be able to use Zipline unsing Quandl data to run a backtest.
In the Anaconda prompt I activate my environment, I installed zipline, then set my API key (until this moment I don't get any error) and finally I ingest the Quandle bunndle and a KeyError:"TURKEY" appears. The following is the lines I type in the Anaconda prompt:

*conda install -c ml4t -c conda-forge -c ranaroussi zipline reloaded*
(this does not give me any problem)

*Set QUANDL_API_KEY= my_api_key*
(this does not give me any problem)

*zipline ingest -b quandl*
and this line gives me the error KeyError: "TURKEY"

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.